# Expand macros of a single file when compiling linux kernel

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, kbuild

I'm interested in expanding the macros of a single Linux kernel file (arch/x86/kernel/nmi.c).
I know that normally one can use gcc -E to expand the macros.
However since the file is part of the Linux kernel, many options need to be passed to gcc. I'm then trying to modify the kernel Makefile to pass the -E flag.

I'm currently modifying the /arch/x86/kernel/Makefile that is the one use to compile nmi.c and call this particular sub-Makefile by
    make M=arch/x86/kernel

I found out that extra gcc flags can be passed by using CFLAGS_nmi.o.
However adding 
    CFLAGS_nmi.o := -E
to the Makefile does not have the expected effect

This is the output after modifying the Makefile

```
~/git/linux$ make M=arch/x86/kernel
CC      arch/x86/kernel/nmi.o
AR      arch/x86/kernel/built-in.a
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 3 modules
```

I would expect the expanded code after the "CC      arch/x86/kernel/nmi.o" line.
I also tried "CFLAGS_nmi.o := -E > nmi.out" to try to redirect the output, but the generated file is empty.

Comment: You could add the `-save-temps=cwd` or `-save-temps=obj` GCC CFLAGS option to dump intermediate files with names based on the .c file (for `-save-temps=cwd`), or with names based on the .o file (for `-save-temps=obj`). The saved .i files contain the preprocessed output.

Comment: you need to see what macros are used by the scripts of compilation and use the same macros

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
CFLAGS_nmi.o := -save-temps=obj
```

did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Where do we add this flag?